# Bash script stops after including /etc/init.d/functions

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, init

I am creating my first init script on CentOS 7. And I want to run one process as deamon at this script, and trying to use daemon function from /etc/init.d/functions file, but when I include this script execution stops.

Suppose my created file is "/etc/init.d/UpdateScript"
If I write:

```
echo "Script start"
. /etc/init.d/functions
echo "After add functions"
```

So after command:
/etc/init.d/UpdateScript start

I have only "Script start" as output. But if I comment "# . /etc/init.d/functions" them I have "After add functions" too but of course "daemon: command not found".
What is the reason of that strange behavior? How to fix it?

Comment: Try `set -x` to see where `/etc/init.d/functions` is exiting.

Comment: `/etc/init.d` is deprecated in CentOS 7 with the switch to systemd. Try sourcing `/lib/lsb/init-functions` for a more portable alternative. You'll need to install the `redhat-lsb-core` package if you don't already have it. Better yet, write a systemd `.service` file instead of an init.d-style startup script.

Comment: Do you use `set -e` in your script?

Comment: "Do you use set -e in your script?" No, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/init.d/functions` ends with `return 0`. When you `source` (or `.`) a shell script you're effectively replacing the `source` call with its content. Since there's a return there, the execution does not continue after it, and `echo "After add functions"` is never executed.

Comment: On what version of CentOS 7 does it end with `return 0`? It doesn't on my 7.2 system. (How could it, even? `return` only works inside functions.)

Comment: Noticed it on my Fedora 26. I'm guessing it's similar on CentOS/RHEL systems, but I don't have one in hand to check.

Comment: Yes, it really ends with "return 0", may be because of deprecation of init.d.